# Is struct name a pointer?

Tags: c, struct, tree, binary-tree

```
typedef struct _Tree{
    int val;
    struct _Tree *left;
    struct _Tree *right;
}Tree;
```

is `Tree` a pointer here?  Does it point to the address of val?

How about this if I define `Tree *node`?
Is `node` a pointer pointing the address of the `Tree`?

if we want to insert `val`, should we use `insert(&node)` or `insert(node)`?

```
void insert_Tree(Tree **root, int key){
if((*root) == NULL){
    (*root) = (Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    (*root)->val = key;
    (*root)->left = NULL;
    (*root)->right = NULL;
    cout<<"insert data "<<key<<endl;
}else if(key< (*root)->val){
    insert_Tree(&(*root)->left, key);
    cout<<"go left"<<endl;
}else{
    insert_Tree(&(*root)->right, key);
    cout<<"go right"<<endl;
}
}
int main(){

Tree *root = NULL;
insert_Tree(&root, 10);
insert_Tree(&root, 20);
insert_Tree(&root, 5);
insert_Tree(&root, 100);
}
```

Comment: Regarding the last question, if your `insert()` is to potentially modify the *value* of the pointer being passed in, then you need to pass it by address (i.e. a pointer to pointer). This is common for list/tree code that passes a head/root pointer in that may be modified. Alternatively you can have the `insert()` function *return* the new pointer value, but I prefer the former option, as I like my API's to manage the list/tree; an not rely on the *caller* to save the new head/root by-overwrite.

Answer (score 5):

`Tree` is not a pointer. It is an *alias* for the user-defined type `struct _Tree`. So when you declare a new variable, instead of typing

```
struct _Tree foo;
```

you can simply type

```
Tree foo;
```

The two are equivalent.

If you declare

```
Tree *node;
```

The unary `*` operator in C is the dereference / indirection operator, and so what you are saying is: `*node`, or the dereferenced value of `node`, is a `Tree`. Or in other words, `node` is a pointer to a `Tree`, i.e., a pointer to a `struct _Tree`.

This pointer is uninitialized until you allocate memory for it:

```
node = malloc (sizeof (Tree));
```

Until this memory is allocated, the pointer is pointing to some undefined place. Once the memory is allocated, you can insert `val` into the node like this:

```
node->val = val;
```

How to insert this `node` itself into the binary tree is an interesting problem. What have you tried?

Comment: thanks verbose, I paste the code.
1)Tree node;
2)Tree *node;
1) and 2) are different, right?
I think 1) node is just another name of Tree
2) *node is a pointer to the Tree structure.
my understanding is right?  Thanks

Comment: `Tree node;` would declare a variable of type `Tree`. `Tree *node` declares a pointer to a `Tree`. They are very different, just like `int a;` and `int *a;`

Comment: Generally which do you recommend when we need to operate the tree, Tree *node or Tree node?  I viewed a lot of programs, Tree *node is more common, what do you think?

Comment: `Tree *node`. The recursion involved in inserting a new node becomes trickier if the root node is allocated on the stack but the left and right children are allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

No, `Tree` is not a pointer or any variable at all, it's a `typedef` alias of `struct _Tree`, and can be used interchangeably with it.

If you declare `Tree *node`, you've declared a pointer to a `Tree` structure, but no actual structure itself.

How your `insert` function works is hard to say without more code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more common way to define this simple structure :

```
typedef struct{
    int val;
    Tree *left;
    Tree *right;
}Tree;
```

Using this structure would normally look like this :

```
Tree top;
Tree left;
Tree right;

top.val = 0;
top.left = &left;
top.right = &right;
```

As you can see, Tree is not a pointer here, but a type structure definition. It acts like a type, which means you can instantiate a variable with the type Tree. Also, you need to use the reference sign (&) to assign the left and right tree pointers, because the structure members (left and right) are pointers to Tree.

Comment: I paste the code, you can see even the val, the template use & sign.

Answer (score 0):

`Tree` is a data type defined by your own code.  Notice how you invoke it in your code, it is in the same place that an `int` or `double` might be.

Since it is a data type, then you can also define it as a pointer:

```
  Tree *root;
```

`root` is a pointer to the structure / data type "Tree".  `root` is only 4 bytes and does **not** allocate a Tree structure.

Or Tree can be a structured/formatted set of storage locations:

```
 Tree  node;
```

`node` is the structure Tree and is allocated actual storage locations.  If you need to pass the address of node then specify: `&node`, this creates a pointer to the storage locations at "node".

I think that your other questions depend on understanding the `Tree` data type.

In general, as you start out in programming, you will NOT need to define double pointers, like `Tree **root`, so re-examine your code and simplify it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. 

If I use Tree *root, it will be root->val.

If I use Tree root, it will be root.val.

When should I use the former and when to use the latter?

Comment: *root is a pointer to a Tree structure.  Pointers are good for building linked lists, trees, etc.  When thinking about this don't mix the names.  If you define `Tree *root;` you would never code root.val.  but you can define `Tree node` and code `node.val`